# Feedback on BSc degree project

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, policy

I do a degree project in computer science. We are around halfway done. I'd like somebody who is knowledgeable to give feedback on our work so far.

Could that be on topic for this site or somewhere else on SE?

Comment: unf this type of question is strongly discouraged on SE sites due to it (maybe?) mainly invoking subjective opinions. however there are some chat rooms where its a fine discussion topic. try [chat] sometime. also note [codereview.se] has generally succeeded with a similar goal, but its an exception... :|

Comment: Code Review has a very narrow mandate: they won't do review for correctness, only style.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Frankly, this is what teachers and teaching assistants are paid for. 
You can also ask peers or more advanced learners you trust.

Reviewing material is generally a bad fit for this platform: it's a task that requires lots of reading (as opposed to a snappy, self-contained question) and has no clear-cut answers.

---

You may also want to consider carefully if you want to share your unpublished work with strangers. All it takes is one person uploading it somewhere, and suddenly it will be on *you* to prove that you did not plagiarize.

Note that I'm *not* saying that you should not share your work and ask for review. There are good ways to do this (that's how science works!) -- posting it anonymously on some website is just not one of them.